# How do I put my NodeJS/ Mongodb site on the internet?

Tags: networking, webserver, node.js

My site/app is running on the localhost. How do I make it available on the www? I want my computer to host the site. I do not want to migrate the site to a host on a Digital Ocean or other hosting service.

I have a Linux machine running Mongod and NodeJS "listening" on port 5000. I can go to the "localhost" and use the site on that port in my browser. I can upload and delete photos on it. I can register and get it to send confirmation emails. I cannot find a guide that shows how to get a domain registered to the site and push the site through my router. Though I know vaguely how some of this is done it is extremely murky. Do I need Apache? Do I need to take certain security measures?

Where do port 80, the machine's public IP, its private IP, the router's IP, and the domain name tie together in a tangible way?

Every search, every guide is giving me near solutions that end up creating misdirection. (I know a Digital Ocean server is probably preferable, but I want to do this as a learning experience.)

Thank you for the link or clear steps for how to make this available on the www. I hope that's clear enough. It's available on the localhost. I want it on the www.

Would I need Nginx for a small site for say, a plumbing company to manage forms on tablets out in the field, customer website, and db management?
What about for an image board?
How about for a news website that hosts videos?
I kind of don't know the steps or what is preferable. I want to build things and learn and build things and be a good boy.

Comment: Is your Internet package with your ISP a business one, or are you trying to do this from home? Have they given you a static IP address?

Comment: I'm doing it from home. I doubt I have a static IP and 80 might even be blocked, but I could use no-IP if need be. I vaguely know what that's about. Mostly in the dark about what else to do.

Comment: Your question is way to broad. And yes, your searches show you external hosting solutions because that is how it’s done: You develop locally and then deploy to an external server. Hosting a website via your ISP is really a bad idea for many reasons.

Comment: Okay, I'll delete it. Curious though. "a bad idea for many reasons." Reasons are security and scalability? I have a 1080ti on in the linux box I was thinking about using in a website as well. I suppose a cloud service makes more sense in any instance there too?

Comment: @Ant It’s not always a bad idea, but it’s generally not recommended since you cannot point a domain name to a dynamic IP and it might be against your ISP’s terms of service. If you’re just trying to learn, I’d recommend learning to set it up on a cheap VPS first, then you can do something fancier like running your web server at home and using a reverse tunnel to make it available through a VPS with a static IP. Or you could try setting up a Tor hidden service on your home computer so you can access it from anywhere through the Tor Browser.

Comment: "Tor hidden service on your home computer." Sounds cool. Hadn't considered it. I already shudder at thinking of copywrite, censoring and moderating on what I might build for a site with user input. Is this more secure than the standard home site setup?

Comment: @Ant It’s not really any more secure, you still need to secure your web server like you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs   that's free.  I think you may have to know some basic git commands first though. To make some commits. And to push to eg github. And then you can follow instructions that heroku guides would give you.

Another solution is your get a VPS(Virtual private server), from a hosting provider. Companies that sell domains often sell hosting too. If it's a virtual private server i.e. a virtual machine they host, then you have full control and could start a nodejs server on that machine. Another solution is digitalocean they let you set up a virtual machine.

Another solution is setting up your own machine, virtual or otherwise. And doing port fowarding on your router, but then I guess if that server gets compromised then unless you are big on network security it might put your other computers at risk, i'm not sure re that one re the risks. Personally when i've run a server from home and put it online it has been just for my access and I secured it with SSH and only(or somebody I authorise), would/could connect to it. And I might have a firewall restricting IPs that access it.   If it were open for anybody to access then i'd probably have wanted another computer running as a firewall between the machine and other computers on the network. Or if it's a VM then perhaps the hypervisor(the thing hosting the VM), could do the security.  But however you do it, if you run your own, you have the security aspect to consider.